# PHP - tcpdf and wamp server

Tags: php, mysql, tcpdf

I'm having really a hard time with TCPDF, in what I am seeing from my searching here in Stack Overflow, I can't find any help in understanding on how to use TCPDF. I can't figure out on how to include tcpdf in my website unlike FPDF, I'll just have to copy paste required folders and files inside the folder of the website then place a `require(fpdf.php);` in the pages. How do I do that in TCPDF?

I can't even figure out how to connect to my database unlike FPDF.

I want to know the basics in understanding TCPDF.

Can someone guide me in understanding TCPDF?

Comment: do you want to convert your html file into pdf ?

Comment: yes... i tried the samples but with mysql query it doesnt work. i dont know how... :(

Answer (score 0):

I have used this [DOMPDF](http://coreyworrell.com/blog/article/php-html-email-pdf-attachment) tutorial to convert my HTML file into PDF. You can send this PDF file to user mail also. It is very easy to understand. Try this and please let me know whether it help you or not. You can see demo [here](http://coreyworrell.com/demos/pdf_email/form.php)

**EDIT :-** If you don't want to send a mail then just remove the following code from `form.php`

```
// Load the SwiftMailer files
        require_once($dir.'/swift/swift_required.php');

        $mailer = new Swift_Mailer(new Swift_MailTransport()); // Create new instance of SwiftMailer

        $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
                       ->setSubject('How To Create and Send An HTML Email w/ a PDF Attachment') // Message subject
                       ->setTo(array($post->email => $post->name)) // Array of people to send to
                       ->setFrom(array('no-reply@net.tutsplus.com' => 'Nettuts+')) // From:
                       ->setBody($html_message, 'text/html') // Attach that HTML message from earlier
                       ->attach(Swift_Attachment::newInstance($pdf_content, 'nettuts.pdf', 'application/pdf')); // Attach the generated PDF from earlier

        // Send the email, and show user message
        if ($mailer->send($message))
            $success = true;
        else
            $error = true;
```

Comment: ok I tried this in my project today and it works perfectly according to my requirement if you have any problem in that let me know

Comment: its useful but i only want where a person can view the data from the database inside a table in a pdf document...

Comment: just remove the mail sending part from that code and user will able to see the PDF file

Comment: tnx mate, ill look into it